# What is the dart equivalent of C#'s Func<bool, String> type, ie how do I declare a strongly typed function variable?

Tags: dart

In C# it is possible to strongly type function variables and parameters.

What is the dart equivalent of this c# code?

```
Func<bool, String> myFunc;
```

I am aware of the `Function` type but it doesn't allow me to define my input and output types, is there any way to acheive this in dart?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Function` allows you to specify your input and output types, and can be used as method parameters and return types, in generics, or they can be given a name using a typedef.

```
/// As a method parameter.
void takesACallback(void Function(int, String) callback) {}

/// As a type parameter.
final mapOfFunctions = <int, String Function(bool)>{};

/// Named with a typedef.
typedef MyCallback = void Function(int);

/// Using the typedef
void myMethod(MyCallback myCallback) {}
```

Comment: Perfect :-) Thanks